# add click function with jQuery not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-ui, google-chrome

the js code is here

```
 var s = "<a id='clickmodifybasic'>修改</a>"

  $("#basicinfoerrordlg").html(s);
  $("#clickmodifybasic").click(modifybasicinfo);
  $("#basicinfoerrordlg").dialog("open");
  return false;
```

it work well on chrome,but not good in IE8.
I got similar error before.
I get the following code from the develop tool of IE8.
 `<A id=clickmodifybasic jQuery1289741833331="94">修改</A>`

Comment: Please elaborate on "not good in IE8" - what exactly happens when you click the link in IE8? The code from developer tool is not relevant, jQuery is binding the events using "on the fly code" you won't see it in the HTML code itself.

Comment: What is `modifybasicinfo`? Is it a function somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a modifyBasicinfo() function already defined, try this code.

```
 var s = "<a id='clickmodifybasic'>修改</a>";

  $("#basicinfoerrordlg").html(s);
  $("#clickmodifybasic").click(function() { modifybasicinfo(); });
  $("#basicinfoerrordlg").dialog("open");
  return false;
```

Don't forget your ";" delimiter after you variable declaration, I have added this in for you.
Hope this helps.

Comment: There's no need for an anonymous wrapper to a function, this just causes extra overhead *and* loses `this` (the context).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I am relitavely new to JS myself.

Answer (score 0):

@WangXing, I have just tested in IE8 with this exact code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ModifyBasicInfo()
{
    alert("clicked");
}

$(function() {
    var s = "<a id='clickmodifybasic'>קישור</a>"
    $("#basicinfoerrordlg").html(s);
    $("#clickmodifybasic").click(ModifyBasicInfo);
});
</script>
<div id="basicinfoerrordlg"></div>
```

It worked fine, and alert appeared when clicking the link so the problem must be with the dialog plugin you're using. What plugin is this exactly? Can you post link so we can reproduce this behavior?

Comment: He's using jQuery UI, and I've used that code like the one he shows before and it works fine, so I doubt it's that.